# Accessing pins of Linux hardware inside device driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

I read [this excellent DIY article](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux) on writing Linux device drivers, but am still not seeing the "forest through the trees" on a major item here. Ultimately the end user software (in user space) needs to communicate with the hardware (that the device drivers are *driving*/wrapping/adapting). Hardware is driven by electricity, and hence software commands need to be translated into hi/lo signals (1s and 0s) that get pushed out onto a circuit and into the connected hardware. A stupid simple example:

```
# Send a connected LED device a command to turn on at the software layer:
led.turnOn();

# In the device driver, somehow, translate this to 0x01 (1, or 00000001):
void turnOn() {
    int signal = 1;

    # Now, *somehow*, push this to the hardware with the following pinout (see below):
}

# Pinout
0   ---------------->  /----------\
0   ---------------->  |          |
0   ---------------->  |          |
0   ---------------->  | Hardware |
0   ---------------->  |          |
0   ---------------->  |          |
0   ---------------->  |          |
1   ---------------->  \----------/
```

What I'm not seeing is: **in the device driver C code, how do I *read/write* bytes/data to and from the underlying hardware device?**

The only theory I could see is that perhaps, because Linux devices are seen as "files" (`dev/led`) to the user space, perhaps writing data, such as 0x01, to `dev/led` is how we send commands to connected devices; and perhaps reading data from devices is how we read data off of them.

Am I heading in the right direction here, or way off track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the nature of the device and how it is connected to the system - it could be memory-mapped, or mapped to some kind of addressable I/O space, or on a bus such as PCI-e or USB, for example. The whole point is to abstract this in the driver so that the programmer doesn't have to care about the low-level details.

For a PCI device for example the board might be mapped to a physical address range. Within this range you might access certain registers to control the hardware. Suppose you have a simple I/O card with a single 32 bit register and the card is mapped to physical address `0xf0000000`. The register is used to control 32 LED outputs and you want to turn on LED 0:

```
volatile uint32_t * const my_card_register = (uint32_t *) 0xf0000000;
                                      // address of PCI card register
*my_card_register |= 0x00000001;      // set bit 0 in register to turn on LED
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul R (+1), let's stick with your bus (USB/PCI) example - how might that work/look? I'm really looking for specifics here, thanks again!

Comment: No problem - simple example now added above.

Comment: Thanks again @Paul R (+1 again) - last question/followup: now that I see this in action, I'm wondering, what determines/sets the physical address (in your example `0xf0000000`) in the first place?

Comment: Well for something like PCI each board can be mapped to a chunk of physical address space - the details are somewhat gnarly and the way you set things up will be platform/OS-dependent. The best thing is to look at the source for a driver for whatever OS and type of device that you're interested in to see how they handle all the low-level details.